Looping through mean of data arrays and plotting
I have a data array of two meter temperatures (t2m). I created a dictionary of weather regime values (0-3; Assigncluster) and corresponding date information as datetime objects (PCs_todatetime).
I have looped over the regimes to get the mean of the t2m in each regime (i.e. mean of t2m in regime 0, in regime 1, etc.). When I plot these means they look very similar and I am worried they are summing across each regime, therefore the first regime would be correct, but then the second regime would be a combination of t2m for regime 0 and regime 1 dates.
I also want to then get the anomalies for each regime, taking the regime for each mean and subtracting from all t2m data (Tr_all).  Below is what I have for code currently, but the anomalies were not correct - they were summing across each regime, like what I stated with my concern above.
#Getting t2m data for all years (1980-2021) in as datetime objects for input into regime// will then have t2m climatology for each regime
saved = False
if saved == False:
    year = \[1981+i for i in range (0,41)\]
    first = True
    for yr in (year):
        leap = dt.datetime(yr,12,31).timetuple().tm_yday == 366
        if leap == True:
            endday = 151
        else:
            endday = 150
        dates = [dt.datetime(yr-1,11,1) + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0,endday)]
        for dy in dates:
            yyyymmdd = dt.datetime.strftime(dy, '%Y%m%d')
            yyyy = dy.year
            data = '/curtana/merra2t2m/'+str(yyyy)+'/merra2_T2M_SLP_dly_avg_'+yyyymmdd+'.nc4'
            data2 = xr.open_dataset(data)
            temp_data = data2.T2M
            if first == False:
                T_all = xr.concat([T_all,temp_data], dim='time')
            else:
                T_all = temp_data
                first = False
    #print("Here is t2m", T_all)

t2m_data = T_all
t2m_clim = t2m_data.mean(dim='time')
#print(t2m_clim)

Assigncluster = np.load('Assignclusterfile.npy')
PCs_todatetime = np.load('PCs_todatetimefile.npy', allow_pickle=True)

#regimes loop; create dictionary

rdict = {}
for i in range(4):
    cluster_x = np.where(Assigncluster == i)[0]
    tag = 'regime' + str(i)
    rdict[tag] = [PCs_todatetime[dy] for dy in cluster_x]
    #print("This is a list of all indexed positions for each cluster", cluster_x)  
    print("How many values in cluster_x", np.shape(cluster_x))
    #print("Here are the dates corresponding to each cluster", rdict)  
t2mmean_regime = np.zeros(\[4,361,576\]) #Considering making an array here to include the    result from the dictionary, however I am not sure if this will actually solve the issue.
first = True
#loop over regimes  
for reg in range(4):
    tag = 'regime' + str(reg)
    thisreg = rdict[tag]
    for dy in range(len(thisreg)):
        yyyymmdd = dt.datetime.strftime(thisreg[dy], '%Y%m%d')
        yyyy = thisreg[dy].year
        data = '/curtana/merra2t2m/'+str(yyyy)+'/merra2_T2M_SLP_dly_avg_'+yyyymmdd+'.nc4'
        data2 = xr.open_dataset(data)
        temp_data = data2.T2M
        if first == False:
            Tr_all = xr.concat(\[Tr_all,temp_data\], dim='time')
        else:
            Tr_all = temp_data
            first = False
    regime_mean = Tr_all.mean(dim='time')
    print('Regime means', regime_mean)
    print('How many values in Regime means array', np.shape(regime_mean))  
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    ax1 = plt.subplot(projection = ccrs.PlateCarree())
    contour = regime_mean.plot.contourf(ax=ax1, cmap='bwr',levels=range(210,320),             add_colorbar=False, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax1.coastlines(color='grey', linewidth=0.75)
    grid = ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True, color='black')
    grid.top_labels = False
    grid.right_labels = False
    domain = [-180,180,-90,90]
    ax1.set_extent(domain, ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax1.set_aspect('auto')
    plt.xlabel('Longitude')
    plt.ylabel('Latitude')

    plt.title('Regime'+str(reg)+'T2M for 1980-2021, NDJFM')
    #colorbar                                                                                        
    cbar = plt.colorbar(contour)
    cbar.ax.set_ylabel('T2M [K]')
    plt.savefig('Regime'+str(reg)+'t2mplottest.png', format='png')

#plot_anomalies; Initially I had the code below included in the loop above over the regimes, however it was summing across the regimes, so I took it out of the loop. Now it is only giving anomalies for the last regime

regime_anomalies = Tr_all - regime_mean
print('Regime Anomalies', regime_anomalies)
regimeanomalies = regime_anomalies.isel(time=0)
#print('Regime Anomalies without time dimension', regimeanomalies)

